# how to forward http 2 protocol version via proxy?

Tags: http, nginx, configuration

I have a simple rails application

```
(browser) -> (nginx latest; proxy_pass) -> rails (latest)
```

How do I configure nginx to notify rails that nginx received an HTTP/2 request via a different header IE:  my_"http_version = 2.0"?  proxy_pass communicates with rails via HTTP 1.1 and I want to know if the original request was http/2.

Thank you!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is similar to what the `X-Forwarded-For` and `X-Forwarded-Proto` headers are used for, but there not a [standard header](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_header_fields) used to communicate the HTTP protocol version to the backend.  I recommend using this:

```
proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto-Version $http2;
```

The `$http2` variables comes from [ngx_http_v2_module](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_v2_module.html) which I presume you are using with Nginx to server HTTP/2.

The difference between `$http2` and `$server_protocol` is that `$http2` works more like a boolean, appearing blank if the HTTP/1 protocol was used.  [`$server_protocol`](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#var_server_protocol) will contain values like "HTTP/1.1" or "HTTP/2.0", so it could also be a good choice depending on your needs.

Answer (score 1):

I can tell you what we've done, but you might find it pretty odd. **If you don't care about trusting and looking through multiple proxies in a row, you can probably get away with a simpler approach like the other answers describe.**

First of all, our application has to support seeing through proxies that are run and maintained by customers. On our app server, we always need to keep in mind that requests may travel through multiple proxies, and for some customers, we actually have to support that use case so that the app can see through multiple proxies to get the original headers.

To support upstream proxies in our app, we have a request filter to analyze the `X-Forwarded-For` header values as well as the remote host IP. Then we take apart all the `X-Forwarded-*` proxy header values and "unwind" them only if we we are sure they were added by trusted proxies whose header configuration has been established contractually (these will be specific pre-configured IPs in our application). This processing is very complicated so that's all I will say about it. But, out of that we get:

1. a list of IPs that represents all the "trustworthy" remote IPs
   in the chain.
2. the most "trustworthy" original header values,
   which will be used by the application for URL generation, etc.

In our app, the only work we do specifically for HTTP/2 is optimization (e.g., do not concatenate JS files), but any HTTP/1.x connections in the proxy chain will bottleneck performance. *So we only care about whether the entire request chain was HTTP/2 from start to finish*. Therefore, we have asked all upstream proxies that support HTTP/2 to implement a special header that we invented, let's call it `H2-IP`.

If any upstream proxy receives an HTTP/2 request, we ask that the proxy **appends** the remote host to the `H2-IP` header. Then, on the server side, we will iterate over the list of trustable remote IPs as passed by our trustworthy configured proxies (#1 above) and make sure that each one is also listed in the H2-IP header.

So for example:

- Trusted proxy IPs (pre-configured): 11.22.33.44, 9.8.7.6, 10.20.30.40, 127.0.0.1, 45.235.235.200
- Remote host: 10.20.30.40
- Is HTTP/2? Yes
- X-Forwarded-For header: 23.45.67.78, 11.22.33.44
- X-Forwarded-Host header: malicious.user.injected.value, app.customer.com, internalproxy.mycompany.com
- X-Forwarded-Proto header: http, https, https
- H2-IP header: 23.45.67.78, 11.22.33.44

In this example, the remote host (10.20.30.40) is found to be a trusted proxy, and we know via contract that this proxy will send all three X-Forwarded-(For|Host|Proto) headers. So we unpeel the last value from each header, use those unpeeled values as the trusted request data, then we repeat the process for each X-Forwarded-For IP until we get to one that isn't a trusted proxy. So here is the data we wind up with:

- Original remote host: **23.45.67.78**
- Original host header: **app.customer.com**  *(note: we threw away an untrusted value)*
- Original scheme: **https**   *(note: we threw away an untrusted value)*
- Trustworthy IP chain: **23.45.67.78 -> 11.22.33.44 -> 10.20.30.40** -> application
- HTTP/2 remote IPs: **23.45.67.78, 11.22.33.44, 10.20.30.40**

Therefore, since the whole trustworthy IP chain is a subset of the HTTP/2 remote IPs, we know this request was fully HTTP/2 from start to finish.

**If you don't care about trusting and looking through multiple proxies in a row, you can probably get away with a simpler approach like the other answers describe.**

Comment: Overkill for what I was looking for, I've found for HTTP/2, those tend to be "human" users rather than bots.  I really enjoyed reading this though, I normally think of everything as being from Browser to server, this was pretty interesting as I had not thought about someone originating from an untrusted connection though to an http2 proxy that would fake things.

Comment: Today the first implementers of HTTP/2 are browsers, but proxies and other clients will all be supporting it soon enough. There's already a mod_proxy_http2 in progress for Apache HTTP server, for example.



True, yes, proxies can fake things, but most of the issue is malicious users pretending to be proxies so they can fool your application in order to evade IP-related security measures, get elevated access, poison caches, etc.

Answer (score 0):

proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-ProtoVersion $server_protocol;

Note: X-Forwarded-ProtoVersion is a made up variable name.  I don't know what the standard one is.